# synchronous execution of function after multiple asynchronous functions

Tags: typescript, asynchronous

I have 3 asynchronous typescript methods, which are to be executed in parallel as i have shown below. I want to execute the last function after all the 3 of them had finished the execution . How could i accompany this.

```
this.getTimeLecs(prevTimeStartStr , nowTimeStartStr).then((result) => {
  // console.log(result);
  this.previousData = result;
});
this.getTimeLecs(nowTimeStartStr, nextTimeStartStr).then((result) =>{
  this.currentData = result;
});
this.getTimeLecs(nextTimeStartStr , nextTimeEnd ),then(result) => {
  this.nextData = result;
};
finalFunction();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `async/await` this can be achieved.

```
export class AsyncAwaitExample {
  constructor() {
  }
  getTimeLecs(str1, str2) {
    return Promise.resolve(str1 + ":" + str2).then(v => console.log(v));
  }
  async getTimeALL() {
    await Promise.all([
      this.getTimeLecs(10, 20),
      this.getTimeLecs(20, 30),
      this.getTimeLecs(30, 40)]
    );
    this.finalCall();
  }
  finalCall() {
    console.log('final call');
  }
}

let example = new AsyncAwaitExample();
example.getTimeALL();
```

Here

```
 await Promise.all([
          this.getTimeLecs(10, 20),
          this.getTimeLecs(20, 30),
          this.getTimeLecs(30, 40)]
        );
```

waits for all the promises to get resolved and then calls `finalCall()` method.
to check whether this works or not, remove `await` from the above code and see the results in console. Check the [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-rce6hl), to see it in action.

Comment: Thanks....someone please  give  due credit to him by up voting the answer

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this situation a few times and a very simple method is to use a counter at the top of the scope. Then at each callback, increment the counter and if it is equal to the total amount of calls, the function is ready to be called.

However, there exists far more glamorous methods such as the async library, which is much better because you can add more functions without re-evaluating the counter and changing each test.

Comment: thanks for the solution...but i would prefer solution from async library